# Desenvolver Plugin para Windows Desktop

Tags: c#, apache-cordova, uwp, cordova-plugin, runtime

Estou a desenvolver um plugin cordova para windows desktop e preciso de utilizar algumas funções nativas, terei que usar o Windows Runtime. Comecei por seguir um tutorial e tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
 - /src
  - /EchoRuntime
  - /bin
  - /obj
  - /Properties
  - EchoPluginRT.cs
  - EchoRuntimeComponent.csproj
  - echopluginProxy.js
 - /www
  - echoplugin.js
 - plugin.xml
```

A nível de código tenho o seguinte:

> plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" id="com.teste.echoplugin" version="0.1.0">
<name>EchoPlug</name>

<description>Echo demo plugin for Apache Cordova</description>
<license>MIT</license>
<keywords></keywords>
<repo></repo>
<issue></issue>

<js-module src="www/echoplugin.js" name="echoplugin">
    <clobbers target="window.echoplugin" />
</js-module>

<!-- windows8 -->
<platform name="windows">
    <js-module src="src/windows/echopluginProxy.js" name="EchoProxy">
        <merges target="" />
    </js-module>

  <framework src="src/windows/EchoRuntime/EchoRuntimeComponent.csproj" custom="true" type="projectReference"/>
</platform>
```

> /www/echoplugin.js

```
var EchoPlugin = {
    // the echo function calls successCallback with the provided text in strInput
    // if strInput is empty, it will call the errorCallback
    echo:function(successCallback, errorCallback, strInput) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback,errorCallback,"EchoPlugin","echo",[strInput]);
    }
}

module.exports = EchoPlugin;
```

> /src/echopluginProxy.js

```
cordova.commandProxy.add("EchoPlugin",{
    echo:function(successCallback,errorCallback,strInput) {
        var res = EchoRuntimeComponent.EchoPluginRT.echo(strInput);

        if(res.indexOf("Error") == 0) {
            errorCallback(res);
        }
        else {
            successCallback(res);
        }
    }
});
```

> /src/EchoRuntime/EchoPluginRT.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace EchoRuntimeComponent
    {
      public sealed class EchoPluginRT
     {
        public static string echo(string valor)
         {
            return " PASSOU AQUI";
         }
     }
    }
```

[image: Chamada da Função]

Só com o JavaScript já consegui por a funcionar agora com a função do C# é que não. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Plugin - https://github.com/claudiohilario/cordova-plugin-udp-data-response